# NodeJS + MySql request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I can not understand With Sql and node.js.
a file app.js:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection ({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: "messenger"
});

var app = express ();

app.get ('/ api', function (req, res, next) {

   connection.connect ();
   connection.query ('SELECT * FROM user_contacts AS uc INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = uc.contact_user_id WHERE uc.user_id = 1', function (err, rows, fields) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log (rows);
   });
   connection.end ();

});
```

After I speak to / API as it happens at the start page. In the console, I see a response from the base. But the browser just hangs out how to get a response from the normal byzy and immediately close the concatenate? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not sending any response, that is why the browser is waiting.

Add

```
res.end();
```

after

```
connection.end();
```

Full code:

```
app.get ('/ api', function (req, res, next) {

   connection.connect ();
   connection.query ('SELECT * FROM user_contacts AS uc INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = uc.contact_user_id WHERE uc.user_id = 1', function (err, rows, fields) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log (rows);
   });
   connection.end ();
   res.end();

});
```